# How can I display datatable datetime column as date in Combo Box when using concatenated string?

Tags: c#

I'm displaying multiple values in a combo box on a Form in a C# Visual Studio GUI
and I'm doing that with the code below. Through concatenating multiple columnames I'm able to display multiple values. The start_date represents a column of datatype datetime and I require to display it as dd/mm/yyyy. How can I display the datetime as date on the form?

```
        trip_DateTableAdapter1.Fill(this.outdoorParadiseDataSet1.Trip_Date);

        DataTable dt = this.outdoorParadiseDataSet1.Trip_Date;

        dt.Columns.Add("ConcatenatedField", typeof(string), "id + ' : ' +  start_date");

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ConcatenatedField";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Combobox's `Format` event

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("start_date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("DateField", typeof(string), "id + ' : ' + start_date");
            DateTime test = new DateTime(2018, 03, 20);
            table.Rows.Add("123", test);
            comboBox1.DataSource = table;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DateField";
      // tried to make your datasource here.
        }

        private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)((DataRowView)e.ListItem).Row["start_date"];
            //found start_date in itemarray. 
            string id = ((DataRowView)e.ListItem).Row["id"].ToString();
            // found id in item array
            string formatValue = date.AddDays(11).ToShortDateString();
            // i added also 11 days to see if the actual date is changing
            e.Value = id + " : " + DateTime.ParseExact(formatValue, "dd/MM/yyyy",  new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));
            // then combined both values, and formatted the datetime as you desired.

        }
```

Hope helps,